# Webpack-dev-server hangs forever trying to fetch Microsoft Teams sourcemaps

Tags: typescript, webpack, microsoft-teams, source-maps

I currently have the problem that a TypeScript app (with Webpack using Webix-Jet) takes forever to load, because apparently it tries to resolve countless source maps to some Microsoft Teams SDK files (most are cryptic, never heard of them). Is there any way to tell Webpack to NOT try to resolve these files? It would help tremendously if I would not have to go on a coffee break every time I try out a new change. (Sorry, I know this is probably a kind of noob question, but I could not find anything at all during hours of google-ing)

For completeness:
I use the following Microsoft modules:

- "@azure/msal-common": "^6.3.0",
- "@microsoft/mgt-teams-msal2-provider": "^2.5.2",
- "@microsoft/teams-js": "^2.0.0",

Webpack modules:

- "webpack": "^5.65.0",
- "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
- "webpack-dev-server": "^4.6.0"

Anyway, here is an excerpt from the Debug Console:

```
Could not read source map for https://teams.microsoft.com/serviceworker.js: Unexpected 404 response from https://teams.microsoft.com/service-worker.js.map: 
Service worker install step network fetch failed for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/3.1-app.min-04cc1c7.js with error: NetworkError: Cache.put() encountered a network error
teams.microsoft.com/serviceworker.js:509
service-worker install was unsuccessful: Error: NetworkError: Cache.put() encountered a network error - https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/3.1-app.min-04cc1c7.js
teams.microsoft.com/serviceworker.js:565
service-worker error while installing or deferring the install: Error: NetworkError: Cache.put() encountered a network error - https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/3.1-app.min-04cc1c7.js. retrying the install without deferring
teams.microsoft.com/serviceworker.js:663
Service worker install step network fetch failed for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/3.1-app.min-04cc1c7.js with error: NetworkError: Cache.put() encountered a network error
teams.microsoft.com/serviceworker.js:509
service-worker install was unsuccessful: Error: NetworkError: Cache.put() encountered a network error - https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/3.1-app.min-04cc1c7.js
teams.microsoft.com/serviceworker.js:565
Uncaught Error Error: NetworkError: Cache.put() encountered a network error - https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/3.1-app.min-04cc1c7.js
    at <anonymous> (teams.microsoft.com/serviceworker.js:510:19)
<anonymous> @ teams.microsoft.com/serviceworker.js:510:19
Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/26397-bd5c1a4b7882cc6e.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/26397-bd5c1a4b7882cc6e.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/92891-ca3f670ed6794e4f.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/92891-ca3f670ed6794e4f.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/811-e63f92f1416c8df5.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/811-e63f92f1416c8df5.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/main-b1e4ed9b3ed03deb.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/main-b1e4ed9b3ed03deb.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/config-prod-3a22ccbe9862424d.js took longer than 2362.742939 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.Heartbeat: 'enableHeartbeatMonitor' flag is NOT enabled
WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/main-locale-en-us-cff42a7be1b1227a.js took longer than 1000.7061630000003 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/breakoutRooms-locale-en-us-0e67cc9904921cea.js took longer than 999.6222250000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/gallery-locale-en-us-542db2e84281e7cf.js took longer than 999.6222250000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/recurrence-locale-en-us-53d925c7d7c5f197.js took longer than 999.6222250000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/messaging-locale-en-us-620cd40bea2eae04.js took longer than 999.6222250000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/main-locale-en-us-cff42a7be1b1227a.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/main-locale-en-us-cff42a7be1b1227a.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/breakoutRooms-locale-en-us-0e67cc9904921cea.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/breakoutRooms-locale-en-us-0e67cc9904921cea.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/12084-5aab56f79de4f47f.js took longer than 999.6222250000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/gallery-locale-en-us-542db2e84281e7cf.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/gallery-locale-en-us-542db2e84281e7cf.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/auth-7ab3c1fb1394218e.js took longer than 999.6222250000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/recurrence-locale-en-us-53d925c7d7c5f197.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/recurrence-locale-en-us-53d925c7d7c5f197.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/messaging-locale-en-us-620cd40bea2eae04.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/messaging-locale-en-us-620cd40bea2eae04.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/12084-5aab56f79de4f47f.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/12084-5aab56f79de4f47f.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/47933-87fca0df6ea48322.js took longer than 999.6222250000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.
WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/26991-3d948da9d9adf704.js took longer than 999.6222250000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/data-schema-d142bb1ae25999a9.js took longer than 999.6222250000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.AtpSafelinksService: Invalid policy found from localStorage
teams.microsoft.com/multi-window/?agent=web&version=22060614805꞉1:4113:69
2022-07-19T22:04:02.153Z deviceManager: No whiteboard camera found
statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/0.2-angular-jquery.min-92954a0.js:114
Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/auth-7ab3c1fb1394218e.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/auth-7ab3c1fb1394218e.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/47933-87fca0df6ea48322.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/47933-87fca0df6ea48322.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/6954-671fc53f6581ddb6.js took longer than 999.6222250000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.Error: Failed to resolve: the task is already resolved
    at o._checkState (https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/3.1-app.min-04cc1c7.js:1:11252581)
    at o.resolve (https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/3.1-app.min-04cc1c7.js:1:11251389)
    at Object.successFunc (https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/3.1-app.min-04cc1c7.js:1:11484687)
    at https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/3.1-app.min-04cc1c7.js:1:11254094
    at a (https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/3.1-app.min-04cc1c7.js:1:11248408)
    at o._resolveCallback (https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/3.1-app.min-04cc1c7.js:1:11254073)
    at https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/3.1-app.min-04cc1c7.js:1:11253965
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at o._resolveSuccesses (https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/3.1-app.min-04cc1c7.js:1:11253883)
    at o._addCallbackSet (https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/3.1-app.min-04cc1c7.js:1:11250395) Unhandled error caught in promise chain
statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/0.2-angular-jquery.min-92954a0.js:114
WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/21938-ffaa2eb74582d5de.js took longer than 999.6222250000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/25553-3e019b4b485d351a.js took longer than 999.6222250000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/26991-3d948da9d9adf704.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/26991-3d948da9d9adf704.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/75916-cdaac387a0f18fbd.js took longer than 999.6000230000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/18243-aed52e9dbe0847a8.js took longer than 999.6000230000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/data-schema-d142bb1ae25999a9.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/data-schema-d142bb1ae25999a9.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/6954-671fc53f6581ddb6.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/6954-671fc53f6581ddb6.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/34295-408faad35f4677d5.js took longer than 999.6000230000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/25553-3e019b4b485d351a.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/25553-3e019b4b485d351a.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/21938-ffaa2eb74582d5de.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/21938-ffaa2eb74582d5de.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/75916-cdaac387a0f18fbd.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/75916-cdaac387a0f18fbd.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
[...]
WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/30351-7b4b5100b2c6422d.js took longer than 998.9314160000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/60891-11b6431f75da9690.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/60891-11b6431f75da9690.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/12257-4261b88f858047de.js took longer than 998.9314160000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/79000-fabb0b32a6e17dad.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/79000-fabb0b32a6e17dad.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/49522-7602b29b507a5a02.js took longer than 998.9314160000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/30351-7b4b5100b2c6422d.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/30351-7b4b5100b2c6422d.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/core-essentials-05b57a88d0d044fb.js took longer than 998.9314160000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/12257-4261b88f858047de.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/12257-4261b88f858047de.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/49522-7602b29b507a5a02.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/49522-7602b29b507a5a02.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/56908-7d754d4129859d9e.js took longer than 998.9314160000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/core-essentials-05b57a88d0d044fb.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/core-essentials-05b57a88d0d044fb.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/28258-5137063a617914b9.js took longer than 998.9314160000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/mw-shell-app-d0ed1db759964392.js took longer than 998.9314160000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/56908-7d754d4129859d9e.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/56908-7d754d4129859d9e.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/13622-97271a15a7c3c875.js took longer than 998.9314160000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/28258-5137063a617914b9.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/28258-5137063a617914b9.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/8240-5dc839804d4f3cdc.js took longer than 998.9314160000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/mw-shell-app-d0ed1db759964392.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/mw-shell-app-d0ed1db759964392.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/71602-93be6124a60c2d52.js took longer than 998.9314160000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/13622-97271a15a7c3c875.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/13622-97271a15a7c3c875.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/44978-7c8ce7dd0f37e927.js took longer than 998.9314160000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/8240-5dc839804d4f3cdc.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/8240-5dc839804d4f3cdc.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/21767-2b1ca70cdbb0cd61.js took longer than 998.9314160000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/71602-93be6124a60c2d52.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/71602-93be6124a60c2d52.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/49517-435b50fa4947cacd.js took longer than 998.9314160000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/44978-7c8ce7dd0f37e927.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/44978-7c8ce7dd0f37e927.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/68978-a520b15ede94d645.js took longer than 998.9314160000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/21767-2b1ca70cdbb0cd61.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/21767-2b1ca70cdbb0cd61.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/88591-ba9f8a04af2b2576.js took longer than 998.9314160000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/49517-435b50fa4947cacd.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/49517-435b50fa4947cacd.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/39494-c0a2e3828efe9f5c.js took longer than 998.9314160000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/68978-a520b15ede94d645.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/68978-a520b15ede94d645.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/34236-97b407d1a43fb6e8.js took longer than 998.9314160000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/88591-ba9f8a04af2b2576.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/88591-ba9f8a04af2b2576.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/6340-33acb892eec9719f.js took longer than 998.9314160000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/39494-c0a2e3828efe9f5c.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/39494-c0a2e3828efe9f5c.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/17330-8c1223f7ec2361f5.js took longer than 998.9314160000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/34236-97b407d1a43fb6e8.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/34236-97b407d1a43fb6e8.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/10103-6466e075983e7a61.js took longer than 998.9314160000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/5592-f5ba1f52aee0ccba.js took longer than 998.9314160000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/39643-3d5d100bc6e9b91b.js took longer than 998.9314160000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/72678-f591b2332fa825c2.js took longer than 998.9314160000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/51517-e024a704a04d7cac.js took longer than 998.9314160000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/6340-33acb892eec9719f.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/6340-33acb892eec9719f.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/17330-8c1223f7ec2361f5.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/17330-8c1223f7ec2361f5.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/10103-6466e075983e7a61.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/10103-6466e075983e7a61.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/52566-706fc0d7efcba7ea.js took longer than 998.9314160000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/33832-68e8c731f5b4da16.js took longer than 998.9314160000002 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/5592-f5ba1f52aee0ccba.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/5592-f5ba1f52aee0ccba.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
[...]
WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/data-resolvers-esp-target-0a5f7b583f3225a9.js took longer than 980.8336510000001 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/79080-f716908af079fdb2.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/79080-f716908af079fdb2.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
WARNING: Processing source-maps of https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/extensibility-locale-en-us-95d27c8a6e3cca79.js took longer than 980.8336510000001 ms so we continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the script to be set.Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/data-resolvers-search-afc0d35a20dab17a.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/data-resolvers-search-afc0d35a20dab17a.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/data-resolvers-esp-target-0a5f7b583f3225a9.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/data-resolvers-esp-target-0a5f7b583f3225a9.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
Could not read source map for https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/teams-modular-packages/hashed-assets/extensibility-locale-en-us-95d27c8a6e3cca79.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/extensibility-locale-en-us-95d27c8a6e3cca79.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
```

Comment: Could you please share any sample that you are setting up?

Comment: What exactly would you want to look at? Happy to provide any sort of snippets that might help - for me: I am completely clueless at where to look at - the webpack.config? or the index.html? or the myapp.ts? or the ms teams config stuff (.fx/...) or thems teams templates stuff (templates/...)? Or the Visual Studio Code tasks.json and launch.json?

Comment: @AndreasP. - Looks like some network issue from your end. Please try it again and also refer this documentation: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/main/concepts/toolkit/providers/teams-msal2.md